# Unknown warnings in mail.warn log file

Tags: debian, postfix

still trying to setup (installation and security) my first server and today I found a few strange lines withing my mail.warn log file.

```
Sep  8 17:41:48 jvps postfix/smtpd[7793]: warning: hostname worker-13.sfj.censys-scanner.com does not resolve to address 192.35.168.218
Sep  8 18:44:10 jvps postfix/smtpd[9990]: warning: hostname zg-0823b-129.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.231.159
Sep  8 23:14:54 jvps postfix/submission/smtpd[19438]: warning: hostname zg-0823a-56.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.219.247
Sep  9 16:26:00 jvps postfix/smtpd[26250]: warning: hostname 26.189.237.221.broad.cd.sc.dynamic.163data.com.cn does not resolve to address 221.237.189.26
Sep  9 16:26:01 jvps postfix/smtpd[26250]: warning: hostname 26.189.237.221.broad.cd.sc.dynamic.163data.com.cn does not resolve to address 221.237.189.26
Sep  9 19:45:53 jvps postfix/smtpd[1008]: warning: hostname zg-0823a-256.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.225.64
Sep  9 23:15:33 jvps postfix/submission/smtpd[8430]: warning: hostname zg-0823b-193.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.234.225
Sep 10 10:10:33 jvps postfix/smtpd[1332]: warning: hostname hn.ly.kd.adsl does not resolve to address 61.163.192.88
Sep 10 10:10:34 jvps postfix/smtpd[1332]: warning: hostname hn.ly.kd.adsl does not resolve to address 61.163.192.88
Sep 10 15:09:48 jvps postfix/smtpd[11980]: warning: hostname worker-15.sfj.censys-scanner.com does not resolve to address 192.35.168.250
Sep 10 19:48:41 jvps postfix/smtpd[21725]: warning: hostname zg-0823b-181.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.234.120
Sep 10 20:55:58 jvps postfix/submission/smtpd[24052]: warning: hostname zg-0823a-206.stretchoid.com does not resolve to address 192.241.224.91
```

Cany anyone explain what this could be? Don't know these hostnames or the IP's and I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are hosts that connected to your mail server and identified themselves by a hostname, but that hostname did not have an address record in the DNS that matched the IP address they connected from. The vast majority of these are spam sources, though one of those in your post is [a data-collecting bot](https://censys.io/). On rare occasions this is someone's legitimate but misconfigured mail server; they usually fix it very quickly because virtually everyone will reject their mail or mark it as spam.

The reason they seem completely out of context is due to one of Debian's many questionable design decisions: They chose to separate mail logs by loglevel. Thus, the rest of the logs pertaining to each of these connections are in other files. Debian creates `mail.info`, `mail.warn` and `mail.err`, each of which contains log entries at those loglevels. Fortunately, they also create `mail.log`, which is complete and contains all log entries. You can search through this log for similar log entries and see the surrounding context. You should also be able to get complete logs from the systemd journal.

Comment: Ah I see, 
So if there an entry like this 

    Sep 10 10:10:33 jvps postfix/smtpd[1332]: warning: hostname hn.ly.kd.adsl does not resolve to address 61.163.192.88
    Sep 10 10:10:33 jvps postfix/smtpd[1332]: connect from unknown[61.163.192.88]
    Sep 10 10:10:33 jvps postfix/smtpd[1332]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[61.163.192.88]

within the mail.log file there is nothing to be worried about, right? They tried to connect, failed and lost connection ... or is this a "real threat"?

Comment: @Moritz They connected and gave up. That's what you should see with all of them. What you should worry about is if one of them is able to deliver an email. But if you haven't changed the default configuration and made it an open relay, then that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: awesome, thank you for your quick response, appreciate it :)